# Query to perform operations between lines considering the state of a service

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query to return the average value of three operations on the values of a service, the values must be grouped by service. The problem is that the return operations for each of the values are organized in the table in different lines related to the state in which the service is (started, running, ready). Values are in INT format and are representative only.

Below is a sample of my MySQL data table.

```
+---------+------+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
| service |  Id  |    State      |   value_1  |  value_2 | value_3  | 
+---------+------+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
|  Civil  |  01  |   started     |      12    |    16    |     28   |
|  Civil  |  01  |   running     |      32    |    40    |     42   |
|  Civil  |  01  |   ready       |      59    |    61    |     64   |
|  Public |  02  |   started     |      02    |    11    |     12   |
|  Public |  02  |   running     |      13    |    15    |     22   |
|  Public |  02  |   ready       |      29    |    31    |     35   |
| Military|  03  |   started     |      09    |    11    |     18   |
| Military|  03  |   running     |      33    |    41    |     44   |
| Military|  03  |   ready       |      49    |    72    |     74   |
|  Public |  04  |   started     |      12    |    17    |     18   |
|  Public |  04  |   running     |      22    |    23    |     41   |
|  Public |  04  |   ready       |      51    |    53    |     54   |
+---------+------+---------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

The operations I want to do, considering for example the 'Civil' service with Id equal to 01 is:

- (value_3 from the 'running' status line) - (value_1 from the 'started' status line), this would be: 42 - 12 = 30.
- (value_2 of the 'ready' state line) - (value_3 of the 'running' state line), this would be: 61 - 42 = 19.
- (value_1 from the 'ready' state line) - (value_3 from the 'started' state line), this would be: 59 - 28 = 31.

These operations must be done for each set of Id.

The results of the operations must be grouped by service name, returning the average value of the operations.

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| service | avg_op1 | avg_op2 | avg_op3 |      
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  Civil  |   30    |    19   |    31   |  
|  Public |   24.5  |    10.5 |    25   | 
| Military|   35    |    28   |    31   |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

My great difficulty is in making the operations between lines considering the states of the service for the same Id.

Comment: What if there was a value4?

Comment: @Strawberry You mean to say, what if there _were_ a value4.  You need to use the subjunctive (and yes, the subjunctive is still alive in modern English).

Comment: But I'm not in the mood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to turn out the values in your calculations:

```
SELECT
    service,
    AVG(op1) AS avg_op1,
    AVG(op2) AS avg_op2,
    AVG(op3) AS avg_op3
FROM
(
    SELECT
        service,
        Id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'running' THEN value_3 END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'started' THEN value_1 END) AS op1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'ready'   THEN value_2 END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'running' THEN value_3 END) AS op2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'ready'   THEN value_1 END) -
        MAX(CASE WHEN State = 'started' THEN value_3 END) AS op3
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY service, Id
) t
GROUP BY
    service;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: I cannot understand how through the query above we can guarantee that operations are being carried out on states with the same ID.

Comment: @JhonataTridapalli I have amended my answer once from what I originally posted.  We need to do _two_ layers of aggregation here.  First, we aggregate by service _and_ id, to get the operation values.  Then, we aggregate a second time only by service to turn out the averages.  Check out the demo link I have added above.